# can possible make piece of C# code execute only one time at life cycle of code?

Tags: c#

I want to make piece of C# code execute at first use only.
Is that possible?

I tried `static` keyword with Boolean but this executed every time I run the code.

```cs
static bool once;
static string UID;
if (!once)
{
    once = true;
// do your "once" stuff here
UID = HardwareInfo.GenerateUID("MyApp");
}
if (HardwareInfo.GenerateUID("MyApp") != UID) goto Finish;
```

Comment: Please provide code example which leads to "doesn't work as I need" and please explain what is needed.

Comment: @GuruStron 
`static bool once;

if (!once)
{
    once = true;
    // do your "once" stuff here
}` 
but this executed every time i run the code

Comment: Please update the question and add full [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: This clearly is not a full sample.

Comment: @GuruStron Is that clearly now ?

Answer (score 1):

If there is block of code that need to be executed only once, then you need to write it inside a [static constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors),

> A static constructor is used to initialize any static data, or to
> perform a particular action **that needs to be performed only once.**

```
class SimpleClass
{
    //No need to use boolean flag to maintain state of the execution
    static readonly string UID;  
    static SimpleClass()
    {
        UID = HardwareInfo.GenerateUID("MyApp");
    }

    public void FunctionToProcess()
    {
       if (HardwareInfo.GenerateUID("MyApp") != SimpleClass.UID)
       { 
           //Your code goes here
       }
    }
}
```

<sup>**Note:** Code snippet is from MSDN documentation</sup>

Comment: @Ahmedsamy, I updated my answer to support your requirement, can you please let me know if it works